# Using multithreading for a function with a while loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a pretty basic function that iters through a directory, reading files and collecting data, however it does this way too slow and only uses about a quarter of each core (quad-core i5 CPU) for processing power. How can I run the function 4 times simultaneously. Because it's going through a rather large directory, could I have the parameter use random.shuffle()? Here's the code I have now:

```
import multiprocessing

def function():
    while True:
        pass #do the code. variables are assigned inside the function.

with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    pool.map(function)
```

Because the function doesn't take any parameters, what can I do?

Comment: Show an example of what `function()` does.

Comment: `map` takes only one iterable argument, you can create an empty list or tuple

Comment: @haifzhan So then would I have it like this?:
pool.map()
pool.map()
pool.map()pool.map()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't use `map()`, it is said map takes only one iterable argument, theoretically, you either modify your `fuction()` to `function(one_arg)` or try to use an empty list or tuple or other iterable structure but I didn't test it.

I suggest you put all files into queue(can be shared by processes), and share the queue to multiple processes(in your case it is 4).  Use try-except to quit when finish reading a file. Creates 4 processes to consume the files queue and quit until all files are processed.

Queue is easy for you to tell whether there's more files need to be read or not based on `Queue.Empty` and `TimeoutError`

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import Queue

def function(files_queue):
    try:
        filename = files_queue.get(timeout=60)  # set timeout
        with open(filename) as inputs:
            # process lines
            # time consuming work is here
    except (multiprocessing.TimeoutError, Queue.Empty) as toe:
        # queue is empty or timeout
        break 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files_queue = ...  # put all files into queue
    processes = list()

    # here you need a loop to create 4/multiple processes
    p = Process(target=function, args=(files_queue,))

    processes.add(p)
    p.start()

    for pro in processes:
        pro.join()
```

Comment: The function has multiple print functions inside of it, but there's no output. In the last loop, I tried to print pro and I just got <Process(Process-1, stopped[1])>

Answer (score -2):

This method `pool.map(function)` will create 4 threads, not actually 4 processes. All this "multiprocessing" will happen in the same process with 4 threads.

What I suggest is to use the `multiprocessing.Process` according the documentation [here (Python 2)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) or [here (Python 3)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class).